# Телеграм Бот не видит инлайн кнопку

Tags: python, telegram-bot

После всех процедур когда меня перекидывает в основное меню бота, я нажимаю на профиль и ничего не происходит. Ошибок никаких в консоли нету, не понимаю с чем связано

```
btnprof = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Профиль', callback_data='profildone')
btnmod = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Модели', callback_data='modelidone')

profil = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
modeli = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

profil.row(btnprof, btnmod)
modeli.row(btnmod)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_city_message(message):
    global gorod
    gorod = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вы выбрали город {gorod}.')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Сейчас вы находитесь в главном меню бота. Для управления нажимайте на инлайн-кнопки', reply_markup=profil)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_handlerf(call):
    if call.data == 'profildone':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f' Профиль:')
```

Comment: проверил ваш код, после нажатия на кнопку `Профиль` происходит срабатывание и бот присылает сообщение ` Профиль:`

Comment: В том то и дело, что он не присылает. Я без понятия как это чинить

Comment: вы бота пробовали перезапускать? я вам говорю, что ваш код в том виде, котором вы представили код - присылает ответ при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: Да, пробовал перезапускать, но он не присылает. Конкретно по этому я сюда и обратился что бы мне возможно как то помогли.

У меня в какой то момент закрадывалась мысль что это может быть от того, что он постоянно как обработчик действий использует функцию для инлайн кнопки, просившая подтвердить политику сервиса. Такое может быть? И как это чинить вообще

Comment: Удалите весь код и оставьте только эту часть, чтобы проверить. Либо покажите весь ваш код, возможно есть где то другие ошибки. Предварительно спрячьте ваш токен

Comment: У меня была такая же проблема и причину я так и не смог найти, а вот решением стало создание другого бота через bot father, но с тем же самым кодом. В итоге заработало. Есть вероятность, что замена токена может помочь, но это не точно.